# Best way to filter dataframe from finding elements within multiple columns in polars-python

Tags: python, python-polars

I would like to know an elegant way to filter dataframe based on condition that elements within a list are found in multiple columns of the dataframe. For example, I want to filter `df` based on all elements with `to_keep` are found in columns `c1` & `c2`.

```
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"id": [f"row_{x}" for x in range(11)],
                   "c1": np.linspace(0, 20, 11),
                   "c2": np.linspace(0, 10, 11)})

to_keep = [5, 7, 16, 18]

cond1 = df['c1'].map_elements(lambda ser: True if ser in to_keep else False)
cond2 = df['c2'].map_elements(lambda ser: True if ser in to_keep else False)

print(df.filter(cond1 | cond2))
```

Returns the following -

[image]

Comment: Could you please update your question with expected output?

Comment: Your current code looks equivalent to `df.filter(pl.any_horizontal(pl.col('c1', 'c2').is_in(to_keep)))` but it's not entirely clear if the current output is what you expect.